# Modify sc:Link so that it renders no href but onclick event

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, html-rendering

I want to modify the sitecore sc:Link control, so that it doesnt render an a tag with href. I want it to call a js function as onClick event.

The page editor functionality should stay the same.

Which class should I override?

I looked at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Link and LinkProvider, but they dont contain the part which renders the html.

Comment: Any chance you could briefly explain what onClick javascript is going to do?

Comment: It will call a js function. We can say doLinkAction(string LinkUrl, string LinkTargetType). So, it will write onClick="doLinkAction("Url", "_blank")"

Comment: Your actual questions has caught my curiosity so I'm looking at that regardless, and this isn't an answer - but have you considered just adding a class to the link and using jQuery (or similar) to bind a click event based on that class when the page loads?

Comment: I have to do it over the whole project, on many places. Thats why I would prefer a centralized option.

Comment: Be aware that this may lead to SEO issues, I know Google will load in the Javascript now but I don't know if it would follow <a> links without an href (i.e. whether it would actually perform the click). One for one of the black hat SEO experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had fun figuring this out - as it happens it's not too complicated.

First thing I discovered is that Sitecore's Links aren't User Controls, they're Web Controls - which I haven't really worked with before so I don't understand half of what I've just done.

Internally it looks like Sitecore's FieldControl class just collects together a bunch of attributes inside to render that link element - so we're able to override the **PopulateParameters** virtual method (ensuring we call the base method to make the default behaviour still happen) and then specify an onclick attribute.

So this is what the final code of my class looks like.

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:JavascriptLink runat=server></{0}:JavascriptLink>")]
public class JavascriptLink : Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Link
{
    protected override void PopulateParameters(SafeDictionary<string> parameters)
    {
        base.PopulateParameters(parameters);
        parameters.Add("onclick", "alert('test')");
    }
}
```

You'll then need to register the control slightly differently than you would a User Control - since you mentioned in the comments you need to use it globally you'll probably want to register it in the web.config - I was using [this page as a guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config)